# Page Not Found on categories / tags / pages

Tags: errors

Have been trying to fix this problem for the past few days now.

When I try and access the Posts icon on the sidebar, on the dashboard, I cannot access an overview of Categories/Pages/Tags. I can create a new page etc, but can't see all my categories etc.
When accessing this, it directs me to an "oops page not found" page, I've tried changing permalinks and when reaccesing them it gives me Error 404 page not found.

- Flushing permalinks & changing them does nothing
- I have deactivated all plugins, removed old inactive plugins, reactivated them to see the issue to no avail.
- Deactivated the theme trying multiple themes to no avail.
- Tried Error 404 plugins to surface the issue.
- Resetting the HTaccess file to no avail

I am not 100% sure if this caused the issue, but I updated the WooCommerce plugin and this broke the site for some reason, so had to disable all the plugins manually and fix it this way. Then I realised the page error kept coming up. Again, I am not certain this was where the problem arised.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: What role is the account that you're using? Administrator?

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Comment: Have you modified WordPress core?

Comment: No, not that I can think of. Was thinking of resetting the site, but it's too much effort atm.